# Electronic Signature & Joomla

Tags: joomla, signature

I am using Joomla 3 and need to create some online forms for a client (I am using the RSFormPro extension which is great).

However one feature that this extension does not include is the ability for the applicant to add their signature. Does anybody know how I could incorporate such a feature?

Ideally, I would like to use something like https://github.com/brinley/jSignature

If anybody has done this or has experience in jSignature please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question should be aimed at the developers of RSFormPro.

Comment: I have aimed it at them. Also thought I'd try here as I know users have experience of jSignature here

Comment: This is about Joomla extensions and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, you will probably get a better answer on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a 3rd party service called RightSignature http://rightsignature.com and then just embedded their forms into the site.

Here is a working example on a Joomla site: http://www.harrellrealty.us/forms/harrell-guarantor-form

Comment: Thanks for this it looks very interesting, although not quite suited to my current project. Next one though! I already have all my forms created, I was just hoping to embed a jSignature type div at the bottom to finalise.

Answer (score 0):

[Breezing forms](https://crosstec.org/en/downloads/breezingforms-for-joomla.html) has this feature built in and is a Joomla! component.  It's REALLY powerful.

Here's a demo: https://crosstec.org/breezingformsdemo/index.php/breezingforms-demos/bootstrap-based-forms/new-digital-signatures.html